# Сброс пароля git clone?

Tags: git

Выполнял команду  в консоли
git clone ssh://.....

Он 2 раза запросил пароль, его ввел неправильно, а дальше не запрашивает и пишет.

Клонирование в «typp»…
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@repo.trews.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.

Из-за чего это может быть? Ось ubuntu.

Comment: а у вас действительно есть пароль пользователя `git@repo.trews.com` (ну, или того пользователя, которого вы **на самом деле** упомянули в команде `$ git clone ssh://...`)? (а спрашивала у вас программа ssh, скорее всего, фразу, которой зашифрован какой-то из ваших секретных ключей).

Comment: Да, есть. Спрашивала пароль разблокировки ssh

Comment: *пароль разблокировки ssh* — что это такое и кто это у вас спрашивал ???????

Comment: Ну при попытке открыть файл id_rsa он пишет

Разблокировать: id_rsa
The contents of “id_rsa” are locked. In order to view the contents, enter the correct password.

То есть пароль разблокирования ssh ключа.

Comment: И если вместо ssh выбираю http протокол то клонируется нормально. На сайт gitlab добавил ключ ssh.

Comment: обратитесь к администратору вашего сервера для того, чтобы он вам выдал **правильную** инструкцию, как вам надо клонировать с этого сервера. эмпирическим путём мы тут с вами всё равно ничего путного не придумаем.

Comment: Удалось решить проблему выполнив ssh-add и введя пароль ssh ключа 
https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выбора этого пункта в настройках
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо очистить кэш idea. Для этого есть следующий пункт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого пароль должен сброситься

Comment: а что это за программа?

Comment: это intellij-idea

Comment: @manking, Intellij IDEA. Но при чем тут она :D

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. У вопроса отсутствует тег intellij idea.